# How to apply z-index to range pseudo elements

Tags: css, slider, z-index, pseudo-element

I was trying to build a price slider with two thumbs by styling two inputs and moving one on top of the other using `transform: translateY();`. Nevertheless, the thumb from the second input is displayed under the track of first input. I tried setting `z-index` for these pseudo elements, but it did not help at all.
this is html:

```
<input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="800" step="1" value="0">
<input type="range" class="custom-range" min="0" max="800" step="1" value="800">
```

And css(I was using Bootstrap, so some styles come from it; `background: red` added to thumb for visual difference):

```
    :root {
  --input-height: 30px;
  --low-perc: 0%;
  --high-perc: 100%;
}
input {
    height: var(--input-height);
    position: relative;
}
input:nth-of-type(2) {
    transform: translateY(calc(-1 * var(--input-height) - 10px));
}
input::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 123, 255, 0) var(--low-perc), rgb(0, 123, 255) var(--low-perc), #007BFF var(--high-perc), rgba(0, 123, 255, 0) var(--high-perc));
    z-index: 1;
}
input:nth-of-type(2)::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
    height: 0;
    margin-top: --input-height;
}
input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
    background: red;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

What can/should I do in this situation? Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: you need to set position to use z-index but not sure if it will work with those special elements